# How to get the specific value from a database in Firebase using Kotlin in Android Studio?

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

I'm having a hard time trying to get value from the database in firestore.

Here is a picture of my database:

[image]

What I am trying to do is get the two fields from the "Add Post" document as a form of string to pass it onto a different XML textView for location and description. Right now, I get some jibberish on the text when I run it.

[image]

I want to get the titleLocation which is just "Chicago, Illinois" to pop up. How can I do that?

Here is what I have in my activity:

```
package com.example.groupproject

import android.content.ContentValues.TAG

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.Log
import android.widget.Button
import android.widget.TextView
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase
import com.google.firebase.firestore.ktx.firestore
import com.google.firebase.ktx.Firebase

class InspectPostActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var locationTextView: TextView
    private lateinit var reference: DatabaseReference

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_inspect_post)

        // Linking all of the elements to their views
     
        locationTextView = findViewById(R.id.locationView)

        reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().reference.child("Chicago, Illinois").child("locationTitle")

       
        // Sets the text to the database location
        locationTextView.text = reference.toString()
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how I found out how to do it. I got rid of the line that Frank Van Puffelen told me and implemented this instead.

```
// Sets the text to the database location
        val docRef = db.collection("Add Post").document("Eau Claire, Wisconsin")
        docRef.get()
            .addOnSuccessListener { document ->
                if (document != null) {
                    Log.d("Exists", "DocumentSnapshot data: ${document.data}")

                   // locationTextView.text = document.getString("locationTitle")
                    locationTextView.setText(document.getString("titleLocation"))
                    descriptionTextView.setText(document.getString("Description"))
                }
                else {
                    Log.d("noExist", "No Such Document")
                }
            }
```

What I had to do was simply add the lines with this inside of them:

```
document.getString(Name of Textfield)
```

Answer (score 2):

Firebase comes with two NoSQL databases: the Realtime Database, a NoSQL JSON database, and Cloud Firestore, a NoSQL document/collection database. While both are part of Firebase, they are completely separate and the API for one won't work on the other.

The `google-cloud-firestore` tag on your question and screenshot indicate that you're using Cloud Firestore, but the `FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()` in your code is trying to access Firebase's Realtime Database instead. To get the document from Firestore, use the [Firestore API for reading data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data) instead.

Comment: Hey, I got it. I found what my error was. I will post my solution was.

Comment: That makes sense though. I was looking at a lot of various videos and code online, so I implemented that into it because it was the closest I could get.